# Apache2 "configtest failed" when trying to restart

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, debian

i tried to protect a directory in my www-folder by using a .htaccess file which had no effect so i changed line

```
    AllowOverride None
```

in my apache2.conf to

```
    AllowOverride All
```

as root.

now i see that this wasn't the right way to do it. when trying to restart apache using

```
    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart (or stop and start)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
    [FAIL] Starting web server: apache2 failed!
    [warn] The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
    Output of config test was:
    apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on         line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared         object file: No such file or directory
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I changed the line to AllowOverride None again but the problem remains. The apache2 error.log does not contain any information. And Line 140 in the config file is

```
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

as the error message indicates there is no libphp5.so in /usr/lib/apache2/modules just libphp5filter.so

Comment: `ls -la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` returns what? `locate libphp5.so` returns what?

Comment: ls -la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so returns ls: Zugriff auf /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (Access to /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so not possible: File or folder not found.). Locate seems not to be installed this just returns bash: locate: Kommando nicht gefunden. (comand not found)

Comment: find libphp5.so returns no results.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

just did the job. Now I'm not sure if the changes apache2.conf actually caused the problem...

Comment: try for `apt-get install php5.6 libapache2-mod-php5.6` Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I know:) that before you wanted add copy of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. So u have to delete it (ex. site1): **sudo a2dissite site1 && sudo a2ensite default**

Comment: Good answer when you detele the file ``.conf``